# Is there a "typical" usage for private variables?

Tags: javascript

First, my experience with JavaScript is limited to web development and a little self-study.  I want to understand the point of having private members in JavaScript.  Take an example,

```
var myObject = {
    WriteWord: function() {
        var secret = 'word';
        document.writeln(secret);  
    }
};

myObject.WriteWord();
```

Private variable `secret` cannot be seen by the caller.  AFAIK, I can notify potential callers of the existence of `WriteWord` in a few ways:

1. Document the code.  [Like jQuery does](http://api.jquery.com/).
2. For .NET guys, write a custom visual studio intellisense plugin.
3. Read the code directly.

Now let's say I minify and even obfuscate the code.  Its now unreadable.  In my mind, given this scenerio, a lack of documentation is just as good as a private variable.

Is this scenerio uncommon or somehow wrong?  What is the importance of private variables in JavaScript?

Comment: "Private" in programming languages is not to hide code. It is to limit usage.

Comment: In this case, `secret` is a *local* variable. A normal variable in a function...

Comment: @trinithis - Can you expand on "limit usage"?  Do you mean scope?

Comment: Limit means only code you want to access it can access it. (A little oversimplified, but more or less true.)

Comment: Addendum: Private code (I'm using private in a conceptual sense) can be known to the world. A metaphor could be a bank vault. Everyone knows it is there. Only privileged people can enter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scoping variables carefully in JavaScript eliminates the possibility of another script on your page clobbering a variable.

This becomes a valid concern when working with many different JavaScript libraries/files from possibly many different programmers.

Comment: So its in line with the logic that global variables are evil then.

Comment: Sure, you can take it that way. I would be more descriptive and say global variables that don't play nice with others are evil.

Answer (score 3):

The whole purpose of encapsulation and private variables, in Javascript or any other language, is to restrict yourself in a way that **allows the implementation of a class to be changed at any time** without breaking the rest of the code. You can rename secret to any other name or completely remove it and be sure that the code would continue to correctly work.

On the other hand, a public method is a point of coupling between the producer and the consumer and you can't easily change the public interface, method names or arguments without risking to break other parts of the program that depend on it. (This is completely unrelated to wether the code has been obfuscated or how weel docomented it is - if someone is using a public method the coupling will already be there)

Comment: Good points for sure.  Though, I am looking for a JavaScript-centric answer.  I understand encapsulation and the importance of private members from a classical programming perspective (C#/Java).  I don't get it when it comes to prototyping.  I'm trying to bridge the gap in my understanding.

Comment: I don't see how you can get Javascript-specific here though. Encapsulation is a broad, language-agnostic concept.

Comment: I'm imagining a UML diagram for a animal/dog.  Classically, I have a base class, animal.  Dog inherits animal.  Animal can have private members to hide implementation etc (like you said above).  How does this design translate to JavaScript?

Comment: Those are not private, they are protected (since they are part of an outgoing interface that subclasses can use). Javascript doesn't have language support for protected variables so the usual approach is make them public and enforce the protection via convention (like _names_starting_with_an_underscore)

Answer (score 1):

Local ("private") variables are very useful to keep the code readable. Not only because of descriptive names, but also because a developer don't have to keep track of 1000+ variable names.

Also, some variables shouldn't be able to be changed "from the outside". Consider:

```
function (){
    var password = "random word";
    window.passwordAsker = function(){ 
        var asked = prompt("Password?", "");
        if(asked == password) {
            alert("Access granted"); //This should NOT be a real verification method
        }
    }
}
```